# Updating Nodejs from root and have a non root user sees it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, node.js, npm

I have a system (Ubuntu) with a *root* user and a *node* user. The node user is used to lunch Nodejs applications and it has no root privileges for security reasons. The current version of Nodejs is 6. To update it I'm using [N](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) simple by: `npm install -g n` but that requires to be root, so:

```
sudo su -
npm install -g n
n lts //that installs it
n lts //that instruct the system to use it
node --version  //11 Thats great!
```

Now tho, when I return to the *node* user `sudo su node -` and I ask for the Nodejs version is still version 6, and if try to do `n lts` from *node* user it gives me a bunch of errors related with permission since N was installed from root (BTW I cannot install N from *node* user).

How do I need to approach this?